# jQuery multiple image overlay

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of images, that I'd like to be able to show an overlay when rolling over them.

Using jQuery, so far I have

```
$(function(){
$(".box").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
  }
  ,function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
 });        
});​
```

But i'm not sure how to take the above, and make it work for multiple images?

Comment: It should already work for multiple images. As long as $(".box") represents the images you wish to use, then it should work already.

Comment: @KJPrice If I roll over one image, the overlay shows on all images at the moment

Comment: @DanTemple that's why we need your HTML code. like KJ said, if `.box` are your images and contains the `.overlay` then you are all set.